# Save automatically generated gui in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How do I save the UI of the Activity? What I mean is that my service notifies the activity, and the activity draws new button. When I click the button I'm moved to another activity, where I have a button which when clicked calls `finish()` method on this activity. Unfortunately, activity which shows up next is just blank, and I don't quite get what happens.

This is a first button which moves to the second activity

```
listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final String[] data = v.getTag().toString().split("\\|");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             mService.sendMessage("acceptRequest|"+data[0]+"|"+data[1]+"|"+data[2]);
            }
        }).start();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CurrentDestination.class);
        i.putExtra("name",data[0]);
        i.putExtra("location",data[1]);
        i.putExtra("action",data[2]);
        startActivityForResult(i,1);
    }
};
```

This is a second button

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      finish();
    }
});
```

I also tried thinks like this:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DriverUpdate.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
        myIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was using this code in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And this code in activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DriverUpdate.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
myIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
myIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(myIntent);
```